Matrix Projection to Pseudo-Unitary Group
I'm trying to find the projection of a given matrix, $\mathbf{Y}\in\mathbb{C}^{2N\times 2N}$, to the pseudo unitary group. The problem can be formulated as follows:
\[
 \min_{\mathbf{X}}\left\Vert\mathbf{Y} - \mathbf{X}\right\Vert_F \]
Subject to
\[ \mathbf{X}^H \Sigma_{N,N} \mathbf{X} = \Sigma_{N,N}
\]
where
\[
\Sigma_{p,q} = \text{blkdiag}(\mathbf{I}_p, -\mathbf{I}_q)
\]
 Here, $(\cdot)^H$ denotes the hermatian transpose, $\left\Vert\cdot\right\Vert_F$ denotes the Frobenius norm, $\mathbf{I}_p\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times p}$ denotes the idenitity matrix, $\text{blkdiag}(\cdot)$ denotes the block-diagonal matrix. I believe this problem is related to the orthogonal Procrustes problem, but the constraint is different.
I am looking for a solution or guidance on how to approach this minimization problem.
